# is it reasonable to use a separate grounding rod for TV antenna?

Tags: tv-antenna, grounding

I want to run grounding wires from the antenna and mast to a grounding rod for lightning protection.  But the most direct route from roof to ground is on the opposite side of the house far from the electrical service entry with its existing ground rod.  What is the consensus about not tying the two ground rods together directly with an 80' cable?  Considerations?  Caveats?

Also of note: the proposed rod will be near an outdoor water spigot on the side of the house.  Attach or not?

Comment: running a lightning rod circuit through the electrical service panel would be a really bad idea ... what would you do if you had an antenna tower?

Comment: Probably run a cable exterior straight to ground - but this likely varies by location.  Electrician estimate is the best course of action.

Comment: You want to provide lighting with as short distance as possible to ground.  Lighting will heat up wire to a high temperature, and you want that wire kept away from any thing that can burn, as much as possible.  Away from other paths(metal plumbing pipes) into the house is a good idea also.

Answer (score 0):

Do you wear seat-belts? Electrically bonding multiple grounding rods together is a safety issue. You *may* never experience an event where such bonding provided protection. However, if you do have such an experience, you will be glad you expended the extra cost and effort. In some places, it may be a violation of the electrical code to fail to electrically bond multiple grounding rods. If is a violation of the electrical code in your jurisdiction, and your house catches fire, your insurance company may refuse to pay for the damage or injury or loss of life.

It may be the case that your house already has a [ring ground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_ground). This is a conductor that goes around the foundation of your house. According to the Wikipedia article, the term applies to such conductors that are buried beneath the surface. However, I used to live in a house that had such a conductor above the surface all the way around the foundation. If your house already has a ring ground, you may bond your new ground rod to that ring ground if you have the skill.

And, yes, you should have your lighting protection wire go from the antenna to ground level in as short a route as possible to reduce the risk of side flashes. Don't route the lightning protection wire horizontally along the roof if at all possible. If you do route it horizontally, again, you may be violating your local code, with all the consequences that entails. In fact, whatever work you do, you might want to consult with a licensed electrician to verify you work meets code.

Comment: What is the point of the first sentence? How is wearing a seat belt related to this question? (I'm not saying it's not, just pointing out it's unclear how it is. If it isn't, it's best to remove it). Also, your second sentence is confusing; did you mean "*not* electrically bonding [...]" (emphasis mine)?

Comment: I originally posted this Q in Electrical Engineering because I was seeking a more than superficial understanding of a ring ground in technical terms. But it was moved without my consultation. This reply, aside from the gratuitous snark about seat belts and other scattered condescension, is almost instructive in this regard.

If the mast has a short route to ground, far from other materials, *how* does bonding help and why doesn't it increase the risk of side flashes by providing a better route to the remainder of devices at ground potential in the house during a 30,000 Amp surge?

Answer (score 0):

If subject to the NEC then 810.21(F) requires it to be bonded at the  (1)Intersystem Bonding Termination or (2) to the building grounding electrode system or at one of the  listed location which only includes within 5' of where the metal water piping system enters the building.

> (F) Electrode. The bonding conductor or grounding electrode conductor
> shall be connected as required in (F)(1) through (F)(3).
>
> (1) In Buildings or Structures with an Intersystem Bonding Termination. If
> the building or structure served has an intersystem bonding
> termination as required by 250.94, the bonding conductor shall be
> connected to the intersystem bonding termination.
>
> Informational Note: See Article 100 for the definition of >Intersystem Bonding Termination.
>
> (2) In Buildings or Structures with Grounding Means. If the building
> or structure served has no intersystem bonding termination, the
> bonding conductor or grounding electrode conductor shall be connected
> to the nearest accessible location on the following: (1) The building
> or structure grounding electrode system as covered in 250.50 (2) The
> grounded interior metal water piping systems, within 1.52 m (5 ft)
> from its point of entrance to the building, as covered in 250.52 (3)
> The power service accessible means external to the building, as
> covered in 250.94 (4) The nonflexible metallic power service raceway
> (5) The service equipment enclosure, or (6) The grounding electrode
> conductor or the grounding electrode conductor metal enclosures of the
> power service

Note: Point (3) omitted as it pertains to building without (1) or (2)